# Check if a list of items is sorted according to 2 attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of objects that contains different attributes, like name and index. I have to write a function that check if the index value is given in alphabetical order.

i.e.

```
items = [item3, item1, item2]
# item1.name = arc; item1.index = 12
# item2.name = banana; item2.index = 27
# item3.name = cards; item3.index = 29
checkAlphaOrder(items) # If index corresponds to alphabetical order, returns True
```

This is embarrasing, but I can't find a simple way to do so.

Comment: Not the most efficient, but the most obvious implementation of `checkAlphaOrder` would be `return sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.name) == sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.index)`

Comment: @DeepSpace, But I believe your solution will be dependent on how `__eq__` is defined for class objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DeepSpace answer is the best so far.

```
return sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.name) == sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.index)
```

Comment: Note this is pretty expensive as it involves 2 full sorts. It's possible to do this with one sort and a lazy comparison via `all`.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
all(items[i].name <= items[i + 1].name and items[i].index <= items[i + 1].index
    for i in range(len(items) - 1))
```

It would compare the name and index values of each consecutive pairs of elements. If each pair appear in ascending order of name and index, the whole list must be sorted.

Comment: A non-sorted list of items will also be valid, e.g. `[('banana', 27), ('arc', 12), ('cards', 29)]`.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to sort your list of objects by name. Then check `index` attributes are consistent via `all` and a generator comprehension:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, name, index):
        self.name = name
        self.index = index

items = [MyClass('arc', 12), MyClass('banana', 27), MyClass('cards', 29)]

name_sorted = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.name)
validate_res = all(i.index < j.index for i, j in zip(name_sorted, name_sorted[1:]))
```